# Reading MachineGuid from registry

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I'm trying to read the MachineGuid from the registry manually. This works and `RegQueryValueEx` gives me the value I'm looking for but each character has a null termination character after them, why is this happening?

code:

```
string read_reg_sz() 
{
    char Buffer[_MAX_PATH];
    char dwMHz[_MAX_PATH] = {0};
    DWORD BufSize = _MAX_PATH;
    DWORD dataType = REG_SZ;
    HKEY hKey;
    long lError = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography"), NULL, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);
    if (lError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
            NULL,
            lError,
            0,
            (LPWSTR)Buffer,
            _MAX_PATH,
            0);
        cout << lError << endl;
        return "N/A";
    }
    int val = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, L"MachineGuid", NULL, &dataType, (LPBYTE)&dwMHz, &BufSize);
    if (val == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout << "succes!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "failed!" << endl;
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    cout << "\n reg data read: " << dwMHz;
    return dwMHz;
}
```

The result is :
[image: showing result]

This only shows 1 character of my MachineGuid, which does start with an 'f'. So I added a breakpoint in Visual Studio to check the value of the `dwMHz` array after the regquery call and this is how it looked:
[image: regquery call result]

So why is my result array polluted with null-termination characters?

Comment: You have read a Unicode string into a char buffer.

Comment: You are reading a utf-16 encoded string, every character takes 2 bytes.  Usually the 2nd byte is 0, it won't be if it is Chinese or an accented character.  You ought to [get ahead](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), but can turn the clock back to the previous century by using RegQueryValueExA().   And FormatMessageA(), you came up with that (LPWSTR) cast because the compiler already tried to tell you that you were doing it wrong.  It doesn't work.

Comment: @Hans The error part is actually taken from an example. I'll try to use just ASCII then, thank you.

Comment: Use `wchar_t` instead of `char`